# Por que ao criar um objeto de zoo series as colunas mudam de numeric ou integer para character?

Tags: r, datetime, data, data.frame, timestamp

Boa noite!!! Estou confuso o suficiente. Vou explicar o passa-a-passo até chegar nas dúvidas que por fim não consegui resolver:

Meu objetivo é criar um arquivo onde esteja armazenado as cotações dos tickers onde cada linha é uma data do pregão.

Baixei as cotações pelo Yahoo Finance:

```
tickers <- c("PETR4.SA", "^BVSP", "^DJI", "^FTSE", "CL=F")
teste.dados <- NULL

for (Ticker in tickers){
    teste.dados <- cbind(teste.dados, getSymbols.yahoo(Ticker, env = NULL, return.class = "xts", index.class = "Date", from = dataInicial.teste, to = dataFinal.teste, thresh.bad.data = 0.75, auto.assign = FALSE)[, 4])
}

dataInicial = Sys.Date() - 10 # para a amostra do exemplo

dataFinal = Sys.Date() # hoje
```

`teste.dados` é um objeto xts/zoo.

```
> str(teste.dados)
An 'xts' object on 2020-05-08/2020-05-17 containing:
  Data: num [1:8, 1:6] 18.5 NA 18.1 18.1 17.6 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "PETR4.SA.Close" "BVSP.Close" "DJI.Close" "FTSE.Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ src    : chr "yahoo"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2020-05-18 21:24:04"
```

DÚVIDA 1: Por que raios o arquivo que escrevo pelo código:`write.csv(teste.dados, "C:\\Users\\...\\teste.dados_cotacao_serie_xts_zoo.csv")`, não escreve a coluna de tempo???? Aparece uma coluna " " com uma sequencia numérica igual a ordem de contagem das observações.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para contornar isso, tive a brilhante ideia de pegar e alterar o objeto de xts/zoo para data.frame:

```
teste.dados.df <- data.frame(teste.dados) 
write.csv(teste.dados.df, "C:\\Users\\...\\Mercado_Financeiro\\teste.dados_cotacao_data_frame.csv")
```

Agora aparece a coluna " " e aparece as datas como factor. Perfeito.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

DÚVIDA 2: Por que, raios e trovões, quando crio um objeto zoo, as colunas deixam de ser classificadas como "num" e passam para "chr"?????????????:

```
teste.dados.bd <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\...\\teste.dados_cotacao_data_frame.csv", sep = ",")
```

É um data.frame:

```
> str(teste.dados.bd)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ X               : Factor w/ 8 levels "2020-05-08","2020-05-10",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 $ PETR4.SA.Close  : num  18.5 NA 18.1 18.1 17.6 ...
 $ BVSP.Close      : int  80263 NA 79065 77872 77772 79011 77557 NA
 $ DJI.Close       : num  24331 NA 24222 23765 23248 ...
 $ FTSE.Close      : num  NA NA 5940 5995 5904 ...
 $ CL.F.Close      : num  24.6 24.7 24.5 25.2 25.7 ...
 $ PETR4.SA.Close.1: num  NA 18.5 NA 18.1 18.1 ...
```

Agora crio um objeto date, `tempo <- as.Date(teste.dados.bd$X, format = "%Y-%m-%d")`.
E vou indexar no data.frame para criar uma série temporal, `teste.dados.bd.ts <- zoo(teste.dados.bd, tempo)`.
Nesse momento, ocorre isso:

```
> str(teste.dados.bd.ts)
'zoo' series from 2020-05-08 to 2020-05-17
  Data: chr [1:8, 1:7] "2020-05-08" "2020-05-10" "2020-05-11" "2020-05-12" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:7] "X" "PETR4.SA.Close" "BVSP.Close" "DJI.Close" ...
  Index:  Date[1:8], format: "2020-05-08" "2020-05-10" "2020-05-11" "2020-05-12" "2020-05-13" ...
```

Retiro a coluna "X", por que ela é desnecessária agora:`teste.dados.bd.ts.1 <- subset(teste.dados.bd.ts, select = -c(X))`
E ocorre isso:

```
> > tail(teste.dados.bd.ts.1)
           PETR4.SA.Close BVSP.Close DJI.Close FTSE.Close CL.F.Close
2020-05-11 18.15          79065      24221.99  5939.7     24.51     
2020-05-12 18.14          77872      23764.78  5994.8     25.23     
2020-05-13 17.59          77772      23247.97  5904.1     25.69     
2020-05-14 17.40          79011      23625.34  5741.5     27.73     
2020-05-15 17.15          77557      23685.42  5799.8     29.65     
2020-05-17 <NA>           <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       30.27     
           PETR4.SA.Close.1
2020-05-11 <NA>
2020-05-12 18.15           
2020-05-13 18.14
2020-05-14 17.59           
2020-05-15 17.40
2020-05-17 17.15

> str(teste.dados.bd.ts.1)
'zoo' series from 2020-05-08 to 2020-05-17
  Data: chr [1:8, 1:6] "18.48" NA "18.15" "18.14" "17.59" "17.40" "17.15" NA ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "PETR4.SA.Close" "BVSP.Close" "DJI.Close" "FTSE.Close" ...
  Index:  Date[1:8], format: "2020-05-08" "2020-05-10" "2020-05-11" "2020-05-12" "2020-05-13" ...
```

Não entendi por que as colunas que eram "num" ou "integer" no data frame se tornaram "chr" na série temporal???

Não encontrei onde poderia carregar os dois arquivos aqui, mas as imagens retratam exatamente o que são.
Resumindo: baixei cotações do Yahoo Finance - é um objeto xts. Quero armazená-lo num arquivo csv, porém não carrega a coluna de tempo. Altero para um objeto data.frame, que carrega a coluna de datas, porém, quando torno essa coluna o índice temporal de um objeto zoo, ocorre a alteração das colunas de num ou integer para chr. Não faço a menor ideia do por que disso.

Agradeço toda e qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Já tentou retirar a coluna X antes de transformar num objeto do tipo zoo? Isso pro problema 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suas duas dúvidas tem a ver com o formato da classe zoo e o funcionamento de matrizes no R. Um objeto zoo é uma matriz ordenada e com essa ordem, no seu caso as datas, servindo como um atributo novo chamado Index.

## Dúvida 2

O R só entende matrizes com um tipo, então se uma matriz é criada com tipos diferentes o R sempre tenta converter de uma maneira para que todos os valores tenham o mesmo tipo. No seu caso o R converte todos os valores para character porque não tem como transformar as datas para numeric. A solução seria não usar esses valores no primeiro argumento da função `zoo`.

```
library(zoo)

#Criando uma tabela com 1 coluna de data e duas numéricas
tabela_inicial <- data.frame(
  data = as.Date("2004-01-01") + 0:9,
  valor1 = 1:10,
  valor2 = 11:20
)

#Utilizando todo o data frame

tabela_zoo <- zoo(tabela_inicial, tabela_inicial[, 1])

str(tabela_zoo)
#> 'zoo' series from 2004-01-01 to 2004-01-10
#>   Data: chr [1:10, 1:3] "2004-01-01" "2004-01-02" "2004-01-03" "2004-01-04" ...
#>  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : chr [1:3] "data" "valor1" "valor2"
#>   Index:  Date[1:10], format: "2004-01-01" "2004-01-02" "2004-01-03" "2004-01-04" "2004-01-05" ...

#Retirando a coluna não numérica os valores se mantém numéricos
tabela_zoo <- zoo(tabela_inicial[,-1], tabela_inicial[, 1])

str(tabela_zoo)
#> 'zoo' series from 2004-01-01 to 2004-01-10
#>   Data: int [1:10, 1:2] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : chr [1:2] "valor1" "valor2"
#>   Index:  Date[1:10], format: "2004-01-01" "2004-01-02" "2004-01-03" "2004-01-04" "2004-01-05" ...

#Mostrando que o objeto da classe zoo é uma matriz
is.matrix(tabela_zoo)
#> [1] TRUE
```

## Dúvida 1

A função `write.csv` é escrita para os dados em formato de data.frame ou matrix. Como os objetos classe zoo são no fundo matrizes, a função só considera as dimensões de matriz para a construção da tabela, o que não inclui o atributo novo Index. A solução no caso é transformar em data.frame antes, como você fez, assim a função `write.csv` usa os valores de data, já que para data.frames ela considera os nomes das linhas.

```
# Dimensões da matriz zoo

ncol(tabela_zoo)
#> [1] 2

dimnames(tabela_zoo)
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "valor1" "valor2"
#Matriz só possui duas dimensões, as duas colunas numéricas

dimnames(as.data.frame(tabela_zoo))
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] "2004-01-01" "2004-01-02" "2004-01-03" "2004-01-04" "2004-01-05"
#>  [6] "2004-01-06" "2004-01-07" "2004-01-08" "2004-01-09" "2004-01-10"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "valor1" "valor2"
#As datas são os nomes das linhas, que são lidos pela função write.csv
```

Tem também uma função chamada `write.zoo` no pacote zoo que já conserta isso das matrizes, mas aí você teria que mexer um pouco nela para o resultado ser um csv.

Comment: Jorge, boa tarde. Muito obrigado.